# Вывести определенных пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Имеется таблица *friends* - в ней хранятся данные о друзьях пользователя.
Имеется таблица *users* - в ней хранятся данные о пользователях.
Задача: Вывести из базы всех друзей пользователя *$us_p[id]* у которых значение **onl**, которое находится в таблице *users*, = 1.
Вот мой код который выводит всех друзей пользователя *$us_p[id]*

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE `id_us` = '$us_p[id]' OR `id_kto` = '$us_p[id]' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");

while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{

if ($us_p['id'] == $post['id_us'])$USPInfo=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users_id` = '$post[id_kto]' LIMIT 1"));
if ($us_p['id'] != $post['id_us'])$USPInfo=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users_id` = '$post[id_us]' LIMIT 1"));
echo "$USPInfo[name]";
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Жаль, что вы не показали структуру этих таблиц. Например непонятно "дружба" у вас двусторонняя или это что-то вроде "фоловеров", которые не требуют согласия.

Надеюсь такой запрос поможет:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM 
  users AS u JOIN
  friends AS f ON f.id_us = u.id
WHERE 
  (f.id_kto = :id) AND (u.onl = 1)
```

Comment: Структура таблицы *friends*: **id** - AUTO_INCREMENT, **id_us** - ид пользователя который подал заявку в друзья, **id_kto** -- ид пользователя которому была подана заявка

Comment: дружба требует подтверждения согласия пользователя

Comment: Ок. Когда дружба подтверждена, логично иметь ДВЕ записи на дружбу — где from_id и to_id меняются местами. Это упрощает запросы!
Пофигу кто подал заявку. Важно что теперь Вася друг Пети и Петя друг Васи. А "заявка" это еще не дружба, сталобыть пусть заявки в другой сущности хранятся.

Comment: логично. но когда писал скрипт  об этом не подумал. теперь вот голову ломаю над тем как вывести друзей пользователя у которых в таблице **users** значение *onl* = 1

Comment: а что касается заявок на дружбу - они хранятся в другой таблице

Comment: сделал чтоб добавляло две записи на дружбу... все равно не удается реализовать задуманное